# Laravel 5.3 query (group by relation)

Tags: php, laravel, collections, group-by

## Explanation of current situation

I'm trying to getch all transactions based on a search, and I want to include a grouped by query of all `description` results that were found so I can display them below the results.

So for example, I search between two dates. That works fine, but I might not be able to use `group_by` on those results, since the `date` field is only present in the `transactions` table, so I cannot do a simple `descriptions` query.

## The issue

I actually have no idea how to do this. Right now I am using the following query:

```
$first = auth()->user()->transactions()
        ->with('description')
        ->where('type', 'expense')
        ->where('date', '>=', $this->parseDate()->firstOfMonth()->format('Y-m-d'))
        ->where('date', '<=', $this->parseDate()->lastOfMonth()->format('Y-m-d'))
        ->get();
}
```

`$this->parseDate()` actually just creates a Carbon instance of the search and in a specific format.

This query is displaying the actual results. This all works just fine.

## Example

Let's say there is one `description` called `gas` and there are 5 `transactions` with the `description_id` of `gas`. That means, 5 results will be returned. However, next to these results, I want to return a `grouped_by` version of all found descriptions, counting the total number of `descriptions` and the total `amount` for each `description`. And that would look something like this:

```
Gas    Results: 5    Total amount: $ 542
```

I cannot simply put a `groupBy('description_id)` on the original query like so:

```
$second = $first->groupBy('description_id');
```

Since that will simply return a collection containing one item, which contains the original collection again.

Any pointers?

## Tables (Stripped)

```
CREATE TABLE `transactions` (
`id`,
  `user_id`,
  `description_id`,
  `name`,
  `type`,
  `date`,
  `amount`,
  `created_at`,
  `updated_at`
)

CREATE TABLE `descriptions` (
`id`,
  `user_id`,
  `name`,
  `created_at`,
  `updated_at`
)
```

## Relations

```
Description->belongsTo('Transaction');
Transaction->hasMany('Description');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got what I wanted to achieve to work like this:

```
$new_array = [];

foreach($transactions as $transaction)
{
    $new_array[] = ['name' => $transaction->description->name, 'amount' => $transaction->amount];
}

$collection = collect($new_array)->groupBy('name');
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're getting the related modelsq of a single `Transaction` then group by doesn't make sense. You already retrieve have the correct group.

On the other hand you can do things like: `->count()` or `->max("columname")` to get the individual aggregates. Check https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#retrieving-aggregates for more info for this.

Since the eloquent query builder is essentially the fluent query builder you could probably also do:

```
$first = auth()->user()->transactions()
    ->with('description')
    ->where('type', 'expense')
    ->where('date', '>=', $this->parseDate()->firstOfMonth()->format('Y-m-d'))
    ->where('date', '<=', $this->parseDate()->lastOfMonth()->format('Y-m-d'))
    ->select("transaction.*", \DB::raw("count() count"), \DB::raw("sum(description.amount)"))
    ->get()
```

Or something along those lines. This is based on https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#selects

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Couldn't get it to work like this though, but I will look into it more for sure since it's a better solution than mine.